# Dataprep doesn't works - Cloud Dataflow Service Agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

I made a mistake deleting an user `service-[project number]@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com` in Service accounts, I should have deleted another user.
After that, the Dataprep stopped running the jobs.

I've checked all guidelines about dataflow and dataprep: if the API is enable (yes, it is). If there is a proper service account (yes). But I don't know what rules to assign to these accounts.

I tried assigning the "Cloud Dataflow Service Agent" role for this account, but it doesn't appear for me >

[image]
[image]

I tried too assigning another roles, but didn't work.

It all started when I deleted this account erroneously.

Someone knows how solve this?

PS: I'm working progress with my English, sorry for some mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you accidentally deleted the Dataflow service account, disable Dataflow API then re-enable it will create the service account again automatically.

Comment: Hi @Jinjun!

If I do it, probaly I'll lost everthing I had done in Dataprep?

Comment: It didn't work. it continues return error :(

"Workflow failed. Causes: Permissions verification for controller service account failed. IAM role roles/dataflow.worker should be granted to controller service account"

I've checked all assignments ("service-<project-number>@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com") and ("<project-number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"), and still keeps retuning error.

Comment: The error is on controller service account. According to this documentation [Controller Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#controller-service-account), the default controller service account is <project-number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. Are you sure this account has the role roles/dataflow.worker?

Comment: I have no clue what happening. 
The other user (@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com) is correct. I assigned with the correct roles. https://imgur.com/EFS3MZX

Comment: How about disable and re-enable Compute Engine API? When Dataprep was not working, what was the error message from Dataprep?

Comment: Hi @Jinjun!
When I tried disable and re-enable GCE I lost all my jobs in Dataprep, 'cause they are connected (google support info)
I was talking with Support Google Team and they can't solved the problem, and I couldn't wait more and I created a new project.
really thank you for your assist.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling/Enabling the API is not recommended as associated resources will be impacted. You should rather [undelete the default service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/undelete) in the following 30 days. You would need its ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_ID that can be found in the generated logs when it was deleted. Find details [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting_a_service_account).